# WPF Datagrid Column TextBox Allow nullable numerical input C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox

I have a Datagrid col binding a nullable int.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header = "OVR QTY" Width = "5*" Binding = "{Binding OVERRIDE_QTY, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N0}"  ElementStyle="{StaticResource STRIKE_THROUGH}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">                                        
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="ODQTY_PreviewTextInput">
            </EventSetter>                                        
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

In the code, I try to limit it to numbers and null.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$|^[0-9]*[ ][0-9]*[/]{0,1}[1-9]*$|^[1-9]*[/]{0,1}[1-9]*$");

private void ODQTY_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        var result = tb.Text.Insert(tb.SelectionStart, e.Text);
        e.Handled = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) 
            || !regex.IsMatch(result);
}
```

When I type 1 in the cell, and then type backspace to remove the 1,  the datagrid cell won't accept the blank, which I think it is null (correct if I am wrong).  Not sure why and how to make it accept null in the cell.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but your code might be a little more readable if you only did one cast of `sender` and only one calculation of the resulting string. i.e: `var textbox = sender as TextBox; var result = textbox.Text.Insert(textbox.SelectionStart, e.Text); e.Handled = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) || !regex.IsMatch(result);`. It will also be easier to debug by setting a breakpoint at the `result` assignment to see it's actual value...

Comment: @RufusL Good suggestion. thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xaml

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header = "OVR QTY" Width = "5*" Binding = "{Binding OVERRIDE_QTY, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged, .......
```

Add this:

```
TargetNullValue=''
```

Look like this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header = "OVR QTY" Width = "5*" Binding = "{Binding OVERRIDE_QTY, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue='', StringFormat=N0}"  ElementStyle="{StaticResource STRIKE_THROUGH}">
```

I think it'll work.